# If there is hell and heaven in Hinduism. Then why is there rebirth and moksh?

Tags: sin, garuda-purana, heaven

We see the concept of rebirth and moksha , while we also see hell and heaven in Hinduism. Garuda purana says a lot about punishments in hell

Also read https://www.quora.com/If-early-Hinduism-believed-in-reincarnation-why-does-the-Garuda-Purana-contradict-that-and-imply-that-hell-exists/answer/Rami-Sivan?ch=10&share=b80d6faf&srid=hd5LP on this. Is it correct ?

Comment: first, you are asking for opinions. also when citing a reference, quote the reference in your question, putting a link in is not quoting a reference.Providing a link to another forum is not quoting a reference.

Comment: because hell and heaven are temporary, not permanent. no matter where you go,you have to fall back to earth, after your punya and paap quota are finished.